# Different behavior in run and start in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to start multiple processes in a Python program, using `multiprocessing.Queue` to share data between them.

My code is shown as follows, `TestClass` is the process that receives packets from a zmq socket, and feeds them into the queue. There is another process(I took it out from the code) keeps fetching messages from the queue. I also have a script running to publish messages to this zmq channel.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import zmq
import time

class TestClass(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__()

        # Setting up connections
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        self.socket.connect("tcp://192.168.0.6:8577")
        self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):

        while True:
            msg = self.socket.recv()
            self.queue.put(msg)


queue = Queue()
c = TestClass(queue)
c.run()
# Do something else
```

If I use `c.run()` to start the process, it runs fine, but it is not started as a Process because it blocks the following statement.

Then I switched to `c.start()` to start the process, but it was stuck at the line `socket.recv()` and cannot get any incoming messages. Can anybody please explain this and suggest a good solution? Thanks

Comment: Do things things work properly if you move everything except `super(...)` and `self.queue = queue` from `__init__` to `run`, and use `c.start()` to launch the process?

Comment: @dano yes, it works... what's the magic behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating the `zmq` socket in the parent process, but then trying to use it in the child. Something in the forking process is breaking the socket, so it's not working when you try using it. You can fix it by simply creating the socket in the child, rather than the parent. This has no negative side effects, since you're not trying to use the socket in the parent to begin with.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import zmq
import time

class TestClass(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        # Setting up connections
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        self.socket.connect("tcp://192.168.0.6:8577")
        self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')

        while True:
            msg = self.socket.recv()
            self.queue.put(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()
    c = TestClass(queue)
    c.start()  # Don't use run()
    # Do something else
```